# Matlab nested for loop into vectorisation

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nested, vectorization

If I have a `for` loop with a nested `for` loop inputting values into a square matrix using one `for` loop, looping through my Y axis and the other looping through my X axis

How could I change this to vectorisation for efficiency

```
g=zeros(f);

%y loop
for u = 1:f
    %x loop
    for v = 1:f
        g(u,v) = exp(-(((u-u0)^2)+((v-u0)^2))/(2*(sigma^2)))  
    end
end
```

Comment: To vectorize, knowledge about `calculation` is necessary. Besides this your code is invalid, a `end` is missing.

Comment: My code works like this, this is just my example from the full thing, I am just trying to change the working if statement into vectorisation

Comment: I assume you mean FOR loop, not IF statement

Comment: yes edited to add calculation and yes for loop

Comment: Your u and v variables are vectorized. Are you wanting to vectorized the calculation of g? Can you show the full code? We'd have a better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish by doing so.

Answer (score 5):

You could replace your for loops with the following:

```
u = ((1:f) - u0).^2;
v = ((1:f) - v0).^2;
g = exp(-bsxfun(@plus,u',v)/(2*sigma^2));
```

EDIT:

In more recent versions of MATLAB (R2016b and newer) you can calculate this without the `bsxfun`, due to the new implicit expansion that MATLAB does:

```
u = ((1:f) - u0).^2;
v = ((1:f) - v0).^2;
g = exp((u'+v)/(2*sigma^2));
```

This should [in theory](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/#comment-46516) be just as fast, if not faster than `bsxfun`.

Comment: I saw that, beat you by about 12 seconds :D

Comment: I think you need to transpose `u`, not `v`. Of course in this case it doesn't matter, as both vectors are the same (if v0 equals u0 as in the OP)

Comment: Good spotting. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

use `meshgrid`

```
 [u v] = meshgrid(1:f);
 g = exp(-(((u-u0).^2)+((v-u0).^2))/(2*(sigma^2))) ;
```

This assumes, `sigma`, `u0` etc are scalars...

Comment: u0 is a vector of size f

Comment: check again about that, if that is so your code in the question is invalid. What are you trying to get here? a 2-D Gaussian or something else? edit your question accordingly.